# Dash App background callbacks not running when added to Celery

Tags: python, docker, redis, celery, plotly-dash

I'm trying to get the sample 4 from Dash background callbacks to work https://dash.plotly.com/background-callbacks.
I have a redis broker running in a docker container which I'm connecting to using celery exactly as shown in the sample code

[image: redis broker in docker]

```
celery_app = Celery(
    __name__, broker="redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0", backend="redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1")
background_callback_manager = CeleryManager(celery_app)
```

I can get Celery to connect to Redis using the following

```
celery -A main.celery_app  worker --loglevel=info
```

[image]

Everything seems to be setup correctly as the callbacks get added as tasks in Celery which I'm checking using flower

[image: Tasks queue in celery using flower]
[image: Web page waiting for the task to finish]

but the tasks never start running. Is there something I'm missing to get the tasks to run?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and what I found is that if I have scheduled celery tasks the background callbacks are registered but never (or at least not in the time I spent waiting) ran. When I got rid off of all other celery tasks, the background callbacks ran just fine. Currently I am looking for a way to split the queues so background callbacks have dedicated workers for them but if that does not help I will probably resort to using Jenkins to run the scheduled tasks.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).